# Determine the Row and Value that was selected on an DevExpress XtraGrid DropDown Control?

Tags: combobox, devexpress, xtragrid

I have a grid that contains a ComboBoxEdit repository editor.  When the user selects an Item in the Drop Down, I need to determine the Row (in the grid) and the Value that was selected.  Which event, etc. can I use to determine these values?

Thanks!!

bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `SelectedValueChanged`, `SelectedIndexChanged` or `EditValueChanged` event of the repositoryItem (ComboBox) to accomplish this task.

```
repositoryItemComboBox1.SelectedValueChanged += new EventHandler(repositoryItemComboBox1_SelectedValueChanged);
```

To get the values you have to use some method of xtragrid. At first i show you an example how to get the row:

```
object row = grdvView.GetRow(grdvView.FocusedRowHandle);
```

If you are using DataBinding on your Grid you can cast the Row to your specific type like this:

```
MyClass row = grdvView.GetRow(grdvView.FocusedRowHandle) as MyClass;
```

So you get the BusinessObject back.

To get the Value from the ComboBox you have to determine the cell value.

```
object value = grdvView.GetRowCellValue(grdvView.FocusedRowHandle, colWhereComboBoxIsItem);
```

Hint: DevExpress recommend you to use LookUpEdit instead of ComboBox. If you need further assistance dont hesitate to contact me.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

GridControl's View provide several events to handle cell editing:

- When an end-user types or deletes a character within a cell or chooses a value from the drop-down editor, the [ColumnView.CellValueChanging](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_CellValueChangingtopic) event is raised.
- After the value has been modified and the editor has been closed, the [ColumnView.CellValueChanged](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_CellValueChangedtopic) event is generated.

These events provides a parameter whose the `Column` and the `RowHandle` properties can be used to identify the row and column containing the edited cell.